# Trying to exec svn ls command in a nodejs child process returning error

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to run an `svn ls <path>` command when I try it out I get an error stating

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file '.svn/entries': No such file or directory
```

which is the standard error you would get for trying to run the command without a path and in a directory that is not version controlled by SVN. But the thing is when I console.log my command before executing it it specifically states the full, valid, path to a remote SVN repository.

e.g., `svn ls https://svn.example.com/this/is/a/valid/repo`

If I copy and paste the log into my own bash it lists the directory just fine.

Here's the code I'm tyring to execute

```
function svnls (path) {
    var cp = require('child_process'),
        command = 'svn ls ' + path;

    console.log(command);  // -> svn ls https://svn.example.com/this/is/a/valid/repo
    cp.exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stderr);
    });
}
```

Alternatively I've tried the more verbose method of spawning a bash instance:

```
function svnls (path) {
    var bash = require('child_process').spawn('bash');

    bash.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        var buff = new Buffer(data),
            result = buff.toString('utf8');

        console.log(result);
    }); 

    bash.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        var buff = new Buffer(data),
            error = buff.toString('utf8');

        console.log(error);
    }); 

    bash.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log(code);
    });

    bash.stdin.write('svn ls ' + path);
    bash.stdin.end();
}
```

and it outputs the same error to console as well as the exit code (1).

Does anyone know why this is failing?

Comment: You are only printing the `stderr`. What are the contents of `stdout` and `err`?

Comment: Nothing useful. err is just an object that states the same thing as stderr (and it exited with code 1) and stdout is blank.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Node 0.8.7.

Comment: I'm running 0.9.1-pre, I will try and downgrade to a stable version.

Comment: Stable version would be a good idea. Also, is it possible you have an issue with one of the `options` fields, like current working directory?

Comment: >_< I figured it out. There was an invisible ansii escape character in my readline code that got the path. (related to another question I had about ansi colors in command line prompts.)